# Dealing with seeming outliers in microarray gene expression data

Tags: t-test, biostatistics, paired-comparisons, paired-data, bioinformatics

I have the following microarray gene expression data for one gene let us say. BTW - have similar data for the same subjects across 17000 genes, so I am looking for a generalized solution.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(subjectId = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 
32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 
38L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 
45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 
51L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 
58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L), specimen_type = c("tumor", 
"normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", 
"tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", 
"normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", 
"tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", 
"normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", 
"tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", 
"normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", 
"tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", 
"normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", 
"tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", 
"normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", 
"tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", 
"normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", 
"tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", 
"normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", 
"tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", 
"normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", "tumor", "normal", 
"tumor", "normal"), log2_ratio = c(-2.7595, -3.12275, -3.1005, 
-2.8935, -3.01725, -2.0075, -1.98575, -1.778, -2.637, -2.4925, 
-2.795, -1.5565, -3.11175, -3.0635, -2.73875, -2.568, -2.5235, 
-2.01425, -2.30875, -2.55275, -2.82075, -2.84825, -3.05475, -3.117, 
-3.04425, -2.4045, -3.24125, -2.2845, -2.9165, -3.02025, -2.7415, 
-2.2085, -3.27475, -2.16325, -2.21325, -2.53325, -2.21625, -1.19075, 
-2.81375, -2.54475, -3.043, -2.53775, -2.53325, -2.8535, -2.495, 
-3.07275, -2.77375, -2.3305, -2.6795, -2.25675, -2.6475, -2.4115, 
-3.09975, -2.26175, 1.69675, -2.29725, -3.1775, -2.67475, -3.15, 
-2.808, -2.7965, -2.26825, -2.43175, -2.44175, -3.08675, -2.3425, 
1.268, -2.42125, 2.98175, -2.4815, 1.64275, -1.029, -2.9145, 
-2.80075, -2.9415, -2.71, -2.9045, -2.6085, -2.5085, -3.017, 
-2.8415, -2.767, -2.315, -3.261, -2.9915, -2.77675, -2.8115, 
-2.4095, -3.4475, -3.2485, -2.546, -2.52975, -2.7895, -2.9905, 
-3.01925, -2.482, -3.056, -1.3125, -2.7135, -2.28675, -2.88075, 
-3.25625, -2.96425, -2.65275, -2.4685, -2.7695, -2.29025, -2.889, 
-2.58825, -2.00475, -3.26425, -2.516, -2.4455, -2.88925, -2.671, 
-2.369, -3.154, -2.42375, -2.145, -3.249, 1.988, -1.40775)), row.names = c(NA, 
-122L), vars = list(specimen_type_code), labels = structure(list(
    specimen_type_code = c("PRIMARY TUMOR", "SOLID TISSUE NORMAL"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L), vars = list(
    specimen_type_code), drop = TRUE, .Names = "specimen_type_code"), indices = list(
    c(0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 
    24L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 46L, 
    48L, 50L, 52L, 54L, 56L, 58L, 60L, 62L, 64L, 66L, 68L, 70L, 
    72L, 74L, 76L, 78L, 80L, 82L, 84L, 86L, 88L, 90L, 92L, 94L, 
    96L, 98L, 100L, 102L, 104L, 106L, 108L, 110L, 112L, 114L, 
    116L, 118L, 120L), c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 
    19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 
    43L, 45L, 47L, 49L, 51L, 53L, 55L, 57L, 59L, 61L, 63L, 65L, 
    67L, 69L, 71L, 73L, 75L, 77L, 79L, 81L, 83L, 85L, 87L, 89L, 
    91L, 93L, 95L, 97L, 99L, 101L, 103L, 105L, 107L, 109L, 111L, 
    113L, 115L, 117L, 119L, 121L)), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(61L, 
61L), biggest_group_size = 61L, .Names = c("subjectId", "specimen_type", 
"log2_ratio"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

You can see from the plot that five of the subjects have what can be considered 'outlier' values for the 'tumor' case:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = specimen_type, y = log2_ratio, group = subjectId)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + theme_bw() + ylab('log2 ratio') + xlab('')
```

Below is the plot (note: each line represents a single subject):

[image]

I am trying to run paired t-tests for each gene's difference in differential expression between normal and tumor case across the 61 subjects for which I have data. However, I am concerned that these outliers (perhaps due to measurement errors, or some other reason) skew my results.

Are there best practices to use in handling such data and techniques for removing these types of outliers (all values belonging to such subjects)?

I can use a z-score threshold easily, but not sure if that is the best or even the right way.

Comment: Please post the plot. No need to assume that everyone interested uses R and should run your code.

Comment: Sorry about that....use R so much, don't even think about it.

Comment: How did you calculate your log fold change? It is awkward. Why it is lower than 0 in the most of the cases?

Comment: No idea since I did not calculate it. It is data coming from TCGA study. I am similarly struggling to explain why for many genes half subjects show log fold change that is higher for turmor vs. normal, but for half others it is lower for tumor vs. normal.

Comment: @user3949008 you should ask. You do not understand your data. If you do not want to do it - you can use non-parametric tests for comparison between means, but I recommend you to understand what kind of data you work with. For your case - half lower than 0 and half higher than 0 is absolutely normal if null hypothesis (means are equal) is true.

Comment: Good advice. Can you help with the above 'outlier' question also? I want to know how to deal with this.

Comment: I have a total of 1,958,710 data points (61 subjects, two sepcimen types and 16,055 genes) and the log2_ratio has a mean 0 02 and sd of 1.404144. Looks like the data is scaled.

Comment: According to this - http://www.mrc-lmb.cam.ac.uk/genomes/madanm/microarray/chapter-final.pdf - mean log centering is a common technique. So, I see that is what has been done to this data.